# implicit declaration of function 'getch'

Tags: c

I have a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Even though I get the warning

```
implicit declaration of function 'getch'
```

the program runs fine. Do I miss something? And if I do, why does the program work OK?

Comment: `getch()` or `getchar()`?

Comment: The non-standard `getch()` is in `conio.h` (also non-standard), which you didn't include. It "works" because the return type is compatible with the implicit return type assumed by the compiler: `int`. In short, you were (un)lucky. Consider using [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) instead.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig for your comment (if it was an answer I whould gladly accept)

Comment: I scratch my head for the down vote. Is anything wrong with the question? please help me improve downvoter.

Comment: The tooltip hint for question voting includes the comment *"...shows research effort"*, perhaps that was it (not me). MSVC compiler warning is more helpful: "warning C4013: 'getch' undefined; assuming extern returning int"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get the warning

```
implicit declaration of function 'getch'
```

because you have not include any header that declares `getch`. No such function is declared in the standard headers `<stdio.h>` or `<stdlib.h>`.

In fact, there is no function named `getch` in *any* standard C header.

Prior to the C99 standard, the C language permitted calls to functions with no visible declaration. Such a call would in effect create an implicit declaration of a function returning `int` and taking arguments of whatever (promoted) type you actually passed.

Depending on this has never been a good idea. You should *always* have a proper `#include` directive for the header that declares any library function you use in your program.

C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule and made any call to a function with no visible declaration a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic (That diagnostic is permitted to be a non-fatal error.)

If you're compiling on Windows, if I recall correctly, there's a `getch()` function declared in `<conio.h>`. If you want to use that function, you need to add `#include <conio.h>` to your program.

I do not recommend doing this; using `getch()` is unnecessary and makes your program non-portable. Some Windows development environments make it difficult to run "console programs" (programs that print to standard output rather than creating a GUI); often running such a program creates a temporary window that's destroyed as soon as the program finishes. Calling the standard `getchar()` function is another way to keep the window from vanishing. Or you can execute the program from a command prompt, and its output will appear in your current command window.

If you're compiling on a UNIX-like system, there's another function called `getch()`, declared in `<curses.h>`. I can compile and execute your program on Linux if I add `-lcurses` to the compiler command line. But you shouldn't use that `getch()` function if you haven't first set up the curses environment, and it's fairly clear you don't want to do that.

Ideally, the classic "hello world" program should be just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How you get that to run and let you see the output depends on your environment (which you haven't told us about).

Comment: I am on a windows 7 machine, code::blocks ide, gcc compiler. I just want the program to stop and press a key to exit. `getchar()` works fine but I have to press `enter` also. Thank you for your time and your detailed answer :)

Comment: @jimjim: You can just press <enter>, no need to type another character first. You can try something like `printf("Type <return> to quit: "); fflush(stdout); getchar();`. Or you can run the program from a command window and let it run to completion. (There may be a way to invoke the Windows `getch()` in your environment, but I don't know the details. It might be as simple as adding `#include <conio.h>`.)

Comment: On gcc why do you need to halt the program?

Answer (score 10):

For linux, use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getch (void)
{
        int ch;
        struct termios oldt, newt;

        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt = oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
        ch = getchar();
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);

        return ch;
}
```

For Windows, add this line:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Since there is no clarification in the question, this answer seems to be in reference to gcc...

Comment: Maybe explain a bit, that this is switching the terminal from line mode to character mode, then back again.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu and was thinking why conio.h was not helping

Answer (score -1):

I got stuck in Mac, for use of getch(), as I wanted to stop screen on the certain condition so here how I figured it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()

{

 system( "read -n 1 -s -p \"Press any key to continue...\"" );

 return 0;

}
```

Hope it helps.