# Why does fputc() skips every other character

Tags: c, file, text

I have a small program in C which starts with a menu which is implemented inside a function with a `do{switch{case 1....}while` loop

When case 1 validates it calls another function where a while loop takes `getchar()` values and write them into a file using `fputc()`.
The problem is that it skips every other character.

Is there a trick around it?

So that my `do{} while` menu with its switch case can coexist with an isolated function that hosts my while loop and it's `fputc()` method?

Here a simplified version of the code.....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int menu();
int v1();

int main(void) {
  menu();
  return 0;
}

int menu() {
  int opt;
  do {
    printf("\t 1] v1 \n");
    switch (opt) {
      case 1:
        v1();
    }
    scanf("%i", &opt);
  } while (opt != 100);
  return 0;
}

int v1() {
  FILE *fd;
  char target[10] = "v1.json";
  fd = fopen(target, "at");
  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Error");
  }
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    fputc(c, fd);
  }
  fclose(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Andres Sanchez Muñoz "it skips every other character." --> Do you consider the enter key a character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Similarly with `getchar()`.

Comment: Considering the number of problems this causes, I am amazed that C has no standard function to input a single character, such as one keystroke from the console. MS has `getch()`and `kbhit()`. They may have got a lot of other things wrong, but I like those functions. Sadly they can't be used in standard C.

Comment: @AndresSanchezMuñoz Please edit that into the text of your question, so we can read it with proper formatting.  (Did you know that you can edit your question?  The tiny gray word "edit" below the tags is a button.  Yes, really.)

Comment: @chux , I want the enter key to finish the loop.

Comment: I am sorry about that @zwol , the code is posted now.

Comment: @WeatherVane this may help you outside of MS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612201/implicit-declaration-of-function-getch/29612473#29612473

Comment: Posting your sample input, output seen and output expected is very useful.

Comment: The `while` loop calls `getchar` twice, but `fputc` only once, for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Deanie your link only illustrates my point: obtaining a single input "when-entered" requires a lot of stuff. It is such a common ocurrence and there are so many questions here. I believe the C standard is deficient, although there may be good reasons *why* the committee decided.

Comment: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {` --> `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c  != '\n') {`

Comment: Aside.  Well _declared_ functions in C should not omit `void`.  `int menu();
int v1();` --> `int menu(void);
int v1(void);` - else they lack a signature check.

Comment: In `menu()` you use `opt` before initializing it.

Comment: Absolutely. I aplied the corrections @chux it works fine now . Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c = getchar()) != '\n') { ... }
```

you're reading in *two* characters from `stdin`, not one--because you're calling `getchar()` twice.

In order to fix that, since you already assigned the read `char` to the variable `c`, just use the variable in the second comparison, rather than calling the function once more:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') { ... }
```